# How can I split a string into paragraphs?

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

I have this string:

```
var content = '<?php echo $content; ?>';
```

Which looks like:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: arial black,avant garde; color: #ff0000;"><strong>Dior</strong></span></p><p><span style="color: #339966;">As far as Candy could see there were plenty</span></p><p><span style="color: #339966;">Among those</span></p>
```

I'm looking to divide it into each paragraph so the result:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: arial black,avant garde; color: #ff0000;"><strong>Dior</strong></span></p> 
<p><span style="color: #339966;">As far as Candy could see there were plenty</span></p>
...
```

I think it can be done with regex, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: alright, i wasn't aware. thanks

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Such an edit is only useful if you add the tag, of course ;)

Comment: @Johnsyweb: sorry; thought it was there.

Comment: @Aaron: I'm not sure I understand your question. The HTML is already in in paragraphs. Are you just trying to insert line-break after each `</p>`? If so, it would probably make more sense to do this in the [tag:php] code server-side.

Comment: whoa whoa whoa you should not be just echoing raw text into JS; you're just asking for JS injection.  use a json encoder.  and maybe do something about all the inline styling there; i can understand one-offs for simple things, but `font-family`...?

Comment: can you provide link for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this will get you where you want to be.

You want to use a split on the `</p>` with will create splits on the that string. Here is the resulting html and js.

You will need to fill in the html portion for your page, but that is the code to do the splitting.

**html**

```
<div class="class">
    <p>text 1</p><p>text 2</p>   
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var str = $('.class').html();
str = str.split('</p>');

for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
{ 
  $('.class').html().write(str[i] + "<br>");
}
```

That should be it. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4JFx/90/) with the results.

Comment: How can i, let's say, measure the length of every paragraph? and do an action if the paragraph exceeds a character limit?

Comment: inside that for loop check length of str[i] and have an if block that does the switch.

Comment: If you're going down this route, be aware that the loop code can be done in a single line, too: str = str.split("</p">).str.join("</p><br>"). The way the loop works now, you'll have one <br> too many.

Answer (score 1):

Simple regexp basing on greedy match works and returns array :

```
re = /<p>.*?<\/p>/g
str.match(re)
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works, but I accepted the previous answer. :)

Comment: No problem. Btw, mine is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
var replaced = content.replace(/<\/p>/g, "</p><br>")
```

worth giving a read: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Although that said, if you're generating the content in PHP, why not just insert the <br> when you're generating the content?

Comment: Definitely gonna read that, thank you! I'm taking input from a wysiwyg editor, so my string it's always variable